# Can anyone explain me about react-redux in easy way?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently learning React and I am trying to figure out how to use it with Redux for building a web app. I'm kind of confused on how the two are related/usable together.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should read Redux docs, they have explained it brilliantly in their demo video also https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started